# xsl:key key() function lookup greater than/less than

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0, fxsl

Is there a way to do a key() lookup using greaterthan/ lessthan?

example: key('akeyname', <8) would return all nodes with the key string value less than 8.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for an explanation and a close solution. :)

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to do a key() lookup
>   using greaterthan/ lessthan?
>
> example: key('akeyname', <8) would
>   return all nodes with the key string
>   value less than 8

**No, because the second argument of the [`key()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#function-key) function must be an expression**, but `"<8"` isn't a syntactically legal XPath expression.

**The closest to what you want**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:key name="kLT8" match="num" use="not(. >= 8)"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <result>
   <xsl:copy-of select="key('kLT8', 'true')"/>
  </result>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document**:

```
<nums>
  <num>01</num>
  <num>05</num>
  <num>03</num>
  <num>04</num>
  <num>08</num>
  <num>06</num>
  <num>07</num>
  <num>02</num>
  <num>09</num>
  <num>10</num>
</nums>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<result>
   <num>01</num>
   <num>05</num>
   <num>03</num>
   <num>04</num>
   <num>06</num>
   <num>07</num>
   <num>02</num>
</result>
```

**A more flexible solution is the use of Higher Order Functions (HOFs) in XSLT, which has been implemented for years by the [FXSL library](http://fxsl.sf.net)** (written entirely in XSLT).

Here is the solution using HOFs:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:f="http://fxsl.sf.net/">
 <xsl:import href="../f/func-Operators.xsl"/>
 <xsl:import href="../f/func-filter.xsl"/>

 <xsl:param name="pLimit" as="xs:integer" select="8"/>

 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:sequence select="f:filter(*/number(), f:gt($pLimit))"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the same XML document (above), the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
1 5 3 4 6 7 2
```

**Note**: HOFs will become a standard feature of XPath/XSLT/XQuery with the forthcoming version 3.0.

Comment: +1. Reading your answers is totally useful. Passing true as a key argument is an awesome solution.

Comment: @Flack: You are welcome. I will update this answer soon with something that might be even more interesting.

Comment: A good answer, thanks. At least I know that I am not simply overlooking some simple syntax. I thought the lookup was more like a string, not an xpath statement. I will post a little more context on what I am trying to do when I get a chance.

Comment: @Darin-Walsh: You are welcome. :)   See my update that shows the use of HOFs as a more flexible solution.

Comment: +1 for a solution I didn't think of and also for the FXSL example. Getting more and more interested in FXSL the more I look at it. If you have some recommended resources (except the obvious one, the FXSL site) please share!

Comment: @Per-T: This paper (for FXSL2): http://conferences.idealliance.org/extreme/html/2006/Novatchev01/EML2006Novatchev01.html is probably a good resource. The paper for FXSL1 is here: http://conferences.idealliance.org/extreme/html/2003/Novatchev01/EML2003Novatchev01.html